# issue of creating and match pair game

Tags: c++

I am a newbie of C++ programming and I encounter some bugs while making a match pair game.

When the game is almost finished, A match pair game supposed to be playable . The card with no pair can not match and complete the game.

```
| 1 | 2 |                   
| ------|         
| A | B | 1
| B | A | 2
| ------|    //playable   

| 1 | 2 |
| ------| 
| A | B | 1
| B | C | 2  //unplayable
| ------|
```

using only `class` to store my arry for modularization (maybe not necessary)

Since I set the array size and letter range can change during the game

example: the board size can be changed form 2x2 to 8x8.
the letter shown in the board can be changed form A-D to F-Z

so I created a function to create some random letter with a pair.
I used `char** Side` as a dynamic array to store letter.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void assignchar(char** Side, int* rowsize, int* colsize, char* fletter, char* sletter);

class chararr {

public:

    char fletter = 'A', sletter = 'F';
    int rowsize = 8, colsize = 8, letter = 6;
    int* prowsize = &rowsize;
    int* pcolsize = &colsize;
    int* pletter = &letter;
    char* pfletter = &fletter;
    char* psletter = &sletter;
    char** Side = new char* [*prowsize];

};

int main() {

    chararr arr2;

    assign(arr2.Side, arr2.prowsize, arr2.pcolsize, arr2.pfletter, arr2.psletter);

    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.rowsize; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < arr2.colsize; k++)  // print out the array
        {
            cout<<arr2.Side[i][k]<<endl;
        }
        
    }
    

    return 0;
}
void assign(char** Side, int* prowsize, int* pcolsize, char* fletter, char* sletter) {

    Side = new char* [*prowsize];
    for (int i = 0; i < *prowsize; i++)  //initialize the Side array
        Side[i] = new char[*pcolsize];

    assignchar(Side, prowsize, pcolsize, fletter, sletter);

    return;
}

void assignchar(char** Side, int* rowsize, int* colsize, char* fletter, char* sletter) {

    int  size1 = *rowsize;
    int  size2 = *colsize;
    int  tolsize = size1 * size2;
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    char f = *fletter;
    char s = *sletter;
    char tem;

    tem = f;

    srand(time(NULL));
    
    char pn[100] = { 0 };  // create a temporary array to store the letter (pair)
    for (int i = 1; i <= tolsize; i += 2) {   
        pn[i] = f;
        pn[i - 1] = f;
        f++;
        if (f == s + 1)
        {
            f = tem;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= tolsize; i++)      
    {
        int j = rand() % (tolsize + 1 - i) + i;

        char t = pn[i - 1];
        pn[i - 1] = pn[j - 1];     // assign the letter to array which would not repeat
        pn[j - 1] = t;

        Side[a][b] = pn[i - 1];
        cout<<Side[a][b];      // print out the assigned charater 
        b++;
        if (b == size2 - 1)
        {
            a++;
            b = 0;
        }

    }

    //'65'-'70' A-F
    return;
}
```

This is just a test of the function to check whether it can produce a couple of letter in pair

```
output:

ECCBDFDDBDCBFBCFAFCBAEADAACADEEEBEDFCFBBCBBCEEDDDEFFABBA
```

It seems that the function have produced the letter and assigned into array `Side` successfully,
but the program suppose to print twice of the array `Side`.
It has no reaction after that.

Then I check the program using vs studio and this happened:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whx6A.png)

I have no idea of that since there is no bug detected by the complier.

A huge thanks for answering.

Comment: pointers are not arrays. `void assign(char** Side,` here you pass `Side` by value. Any changes made to this pointer inside the function will not be reflected outside of the funciton. I suppose most of your issues would go away if you use `std::vector` / `std::array` rather than c-arrays and learn about pass by reference vs pass by value

Comment: in total there are way too many pointers in your code. I think you need 0.

Comment: compilers, in general, do not detect bugs - that's down to you

Comment: Card games are interesting in that you can definitely make a simple one without a whole lot of worrying about design. But you can also get good exposure to best practices of OOP/C++ as well. The same goes for dice games.

Comment: You should play the C++ games at "hackerRank", that's THE place where you learn "this" stuff and you get 2 seconds of execution time and it becomes real hard after a month or 2, if you play each day. it's all about sorting puzzles.

Comment: @NaturalDemon I think you'll quickly find that recommending code golf sites is frowned upon here. They are notoriously bad at actually teaching anything, and anyone who goes in without knowing what they're doing already becomes a worse coder for it. Those algorithms can be learned elsewhere, and with best practices in mind. I would never recommend a learner go there to learn anything.

Comment: @sweenish, i have solved alot of these "riddles" after a while you learn to remove their code and start from scratch, unless they prohibit it, you still need to research all the Keywords and stuff from C++ on CPP reference and other sources, it's also goal to not move the actually values and loose time but find a way to solve the issue without moving or copying them. the riddles can be really mind cracking.

Comment: @sweenish it can take you days to crack some of their puzzles and be really nit picking to almost pulling your hair, the same puzzles are on other famous sites as wel.

Comment: You're missing the point. Sure, they can be fun enough. But they are garbage for learning. People trying to learn the language never get pointed to best practices, never get pointed to cppreference.com, never even learn that single-character names are generally bad. My point is **not** about whether the puzzles are tough, it's about whether those sites are good for new learners. They are not.

Comment: @sweenish for the topic starter it seemed suitable because it compares to some of their riddles on what he is doing.

Comment: Nothing about "why is my card game not working" leads to "you should do random puzzles."